# Show that $\int_{\alpha}\frac{1}{z}\, dz=\int_{\beta}\frac{1}{z}\, dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers. Define ways $\alpha,\beta\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ via
>   $$
> \alpha(t):=a\cos(2\pi t)+ia\sin(2\pi t),~~~~~\beta(t):=a\cos(2\pi t)+ib\sin(2\pi t).
> $$
>   Show that
>   $$
> \int_{\alpha}\frac{1}{z}\, dz=\int_{\beta}\frac{1}{z}\, dz.
> $$

$1/z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$.
Both ways are closed ways with start- and endpoint $a$. So to my opinion all conditions of the Cauchy integral theorem are fullfilled clearly except that both ways are homotopic.

I am thinking of
$$
H\colon [0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}, H(x,y):=a\cos(2\pi x)+i(1-y)a\sin(2\pi x)+iyb\sin(2\pi x)
$$
as an appropriate homotopic function.

Anyhow it is
$$
H(x,0)=\alpha(x),~~~~~H(x,1)=\beta(x).
$$

Comment: "Cauchy integral sentence" <- are you a native German speaker? (It's "theorem" in English ;)

Comment: Yes, I am from Germany and have to translate my questions. :-)

Comment: Thought so. You're doing fine in general, but the termini technici of course pose problems. Just don't write "body" when talking about Körper in algebra ("fields" is the term ;-)

Comment: Concerning your question: yes, $H$ is a homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so that suffices. Depending on what you already have at your disposal, there may be nicer arguments possible.

Comment: Okay, so then the cauchy integral theorem can be used here and this shows the statement. the only difficulty i still have is to show that my defined function H is continious.

Comment: Another way to write $H$ is $H(x,\,y) = (1-y)\alpha(x) + y\beta(x)$. Is that enough to argue the continuity?

Comment: Yes, I think so. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continious and linear combinations of them, too.

Comment: Bingo. So you have two homotopic (closed) paths, a closed differential form, you could even leave Cauchy's integral theorem out, if you wished.

Comment: @DanielFischer: how do you call a non-commutative field? In Italian it's called a "body", I never found any reference about it.

Comment: @Andy In German: Schiefkörper, or sometimes, if people aren't exactly as old-fashioned as I, Divisionsalgebra; but some also use Körper for the general thing, and explicitly mention commutativity when needed. In English, skew field, division algebra, division ring, are the terms I'm familiar with. In French, it's also "corps"; I'm not sure what adjective was used to indicate non-commutativity there, but that can also be used to include skew fields.